# RxJava ignore events for X time since last event?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactivex

I'm wondering if there's a clean way to implement an observable which filters out any events that occur within a time window after the most recent emitted event?

I currently have this:

```
    source.timeInterval(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .filter(new Predicate<Timed<Object>>() {
                final long TIME_LIMIT = 10 * 1000;
                long totalTime = 0;

                @Override
                public boolean test(@NonNull Timed<Object> objectTimed) throws Exception {
                    totalTime += objectTimed.time();

                    if (totalTime > TIME_LIMIT) {
                        totalTime = 0;
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .subscribe(objectTimed -> {
                doSomething(objectTimed)
            });
```

This technically does the trick, but requires a bit of extra state in the filter that's a bit ugly and prevents me from using a lambda. Instead, I'd like to see if there's a way to compose observables that would do the same thing.

Comment: I think you need delay observable or Observable.combineLatest

Comment: Delay is not appropriate, as events that arrive during the ignore window should be filtered out entirely. Delay will simply change the time the event arrives, which is not desired here. You'd have to elaborate on combineLatest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like your desire behavior is exactly `throttleFirst()` operator:

[image]

it will emit only the first item at each window of time.

Comment: I agree, throttleWithTimeout( ) or debounce( ) operators.